# Showing that $f$ is not measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm learning about measure theory, specifically measurable functions, and need help with the following problem:

> Let $N$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0, 1]$ and define
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in N  \\ -x, & x \in [0,1] \setminus N \end{cases}$$
>
> $(1)$ Show that $f(x)$ is a non-measurable function.
>
> $(2)$ Show that $\forall a \in \mathbb R$ the set $\{f(x) = a\}$ is measurable.

This problem looks rather simple but I think I'm missing some key points. I tried to prove $(1)$ by contradiction, that is assuming $f$ is measurable but I didn't get far. For $(2)$ my guess is that $m(\{f(x) = a\}) = 0$ (since by definition the Lebesgue measure of a single point is $0$) but I don't know how to show this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for $(1)$: What happens if you take the preimage of $[0,1]$?

Hint for $(2)$: How many points does the set $\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)=a\}$ have?

Comment: The pre-image of $[0, 1]$ is all values of $x$ whose image is $[0, 1]$, i.e. $f^{-1}([0, 1]) = \{x : f(x) = [0, 1]\} = N$. But $N$ is non-measurable by assumption. This is the part where I'm not sure: the pre-image of any measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ is measurable in $\mathbb R$ (this is a well known property of measurable functions). The interval $[0, 1]$ is clearly measurable so it's pre-image must also be measurable by the previous property but we found that the pre-image is $N$ which is not measurable. Contradiction. So $f$ is not measurable. Is that the right way to conclude here?

Comment: Precisely. :) --

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help.

Comment: How can you get the inverse image of [0,1] as N?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f$ is not measurable since $f^{-1}((0,1))=N-\{0\}$.

Comment: who downvoted here?